# Что значит аннтотация @XmlType

Tags: java, xml

Есть класс, который я хочу сериализовать в XML:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"age", "dogName", "owner", "owner2", 
"needCDATA"})
@XmlRootElement
class Dog {
int age;
String dogName;
String owner;
String owner2;
String needCDATA;
Dog() {}}
```

Я не совсем понимаю значение аннотаций, допустим, аннотация `@XmlRootElement` означает что root элемент будет иметь имя класса. А вот для чего аннотация `@XmlType`? В данном примере я вроде бы понимаю - `propOrder = {"age", "dogName", "owner", "owner2", 
"needCDATA"})` задает в какой последовательности будут элементы. Но я встречала также такой вариант этой аннотации:

```
@XmlType(name = "dog")
@XmlRootElement
class Dog {
int age;
String dogName;
String owner;
String owner2;
String needCDATA;
Dog() {}}
```

И я не понимаю, что означает `(name = "dog")`, на что это влияет? Именно  когда это написано перед классом.

Answer (score 1):

При отображении класса в xml name в аннотации влияет только на это

`<xs:complexType name="dog">`

Если параметр name не указан, то будет использовано имя самого класса